# jsPlumb.js and kinetic.js used together

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs, jsplumb

I am creating objects using Kinetic.js.Now i want connect two objects as source and destination using jsPlumb.js.But i am unable to connect them.
My code looks like this

```
var end0=stage.find("#"+source.attrs.id);
var end1=stage.find("#"+destination.attrs.id);


     jsPlumb.makeSource(end0);
     jsPlumb.makeTarget(end1);


jsPlumb.connect({ 
       source:e0,
       target:e1, 
       paintStyle:{ lineWidth:10, strokeStyle:'black' }, 
       endpoint:new jsPlumb.Endpoints.Rectangle({width:10, height:15}), 
       anchor:[ "Perimeter", { shape:"Circle" } ]
    });
```

Can i use them together? If Yes,please give me an example

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.
KineticJS is using canvas, jsPlumb does what it does with SVG.